# strategy.opentrades not true on execution bar close

Tags: pine-script

Is there a way to have strategy.opentrades == true on the execution bar close or a different variable be positive?
Many thanks

With process_orders_on_close = true, orders are executed on bar close. However, after bar close, strategy.opentrades remains false until the next bar.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. As a workaround, you can use a variable for that and figure out if you will be entering a position on the current bar.